# MarkLogic ERROR: XDMP-OLDSTAMP: -- Timestamp too old for forest

Tags: database-replication, marklogic

I have the following MarkLogic 6 configuration cluster configuration:

**Master Cluster**

- Host-1: **Forest-1**, *Failover-Forest-3*, *Failover-Forest-4*
- Host-2: **Forest-2**, **Forest-3**
- Host-3: **Forest-4**, *Failover-Forest-1*, *Failover-Forest-2*

**Replica Cluster #1 (Single Node Cluster)**

- Host-R1: Forest-1, Forest-2, Forest-3, Forest-4

**Replica Cluster #2 (Single Node Cluster)**

- Host-R2: Forest-1, Forest-2, Forest-3, Forest-4

The configured bootstrap hosts are as follows:

1. For **Master Cluster** it's **Host-1**
2. For **Replica Cluster #1** it's **Host-R1**
3. For **Replica Cluster #2** it's **Host-R2**

---

When **Host-1** (*Bootstrap Host of Master Cluster*) is down, the *Failover-Forest-1* on **Host-3** comes up as the local disc fail over for **Forest-1** and the Master Cluster remaines **Available** to applications.

Given that the Bootstrap Host of Master Cluster is down When the Replica Cluster is down for sufficiently long time (say, *20 minutes*) after which I bring the Replica Cluster back up. The QConsole gives the Error `XDMP-OLDSTAMP: fn:unordered(xdmp:eval($xquery, $vars, $options)) -- Timestamp too old for forest Forest-4` when I try to explore the database.

---

**Questions**:

1. Is there any configuration in MarkLogic Admin which defines this timeout after which the foreign cluster gives the error `XDMP-OLDSTAMP`?
2. Where and how are these timestamps maintained in the cluster?

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce your issue with MarkLogic 8.0-4.2

MarkLogic document states that this error could be due to merge timestamp. If the merge timestamp is set to the default of 0 and the database has completed all merges since the last update or delete, then query statements that specify any timestamp older than the current system timestamp will throw the XDMP-OLDSTAMP exception. The error occurs because a merge timestamp value of 0 specifies that no obsolete fragments are to be retained.